# Semantic UI set value of allowadditions dropdown

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

I am working with the regular non React version of semantic UI.

I have a standard dropdown with search added, and configured to allowadditions.
aka a select with

> class='ui fluid search dropdown'

and

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
            allowAdditions: true
        });
```

I am trying to use Jquery (though open to other simple solutions) to set the value of this dropdown. Things such as:

> $('#myDropdown').val('some text');

Do not work. I have also tried things like

> $('#myDropdown option[value="some text"]').attr('selected','selected');

Neither seem to change the value. Is there a way I can set the value, either to an existing value OR to a new one. I need to be able to do both of these however standard approaches seem to fail.

Comment: You are targeting your element initially with a class, then via an ID?

Comment: Yes, because I have about 8 dropdowns. On the initial setup I set all the dropdowns to allowAdditions : true. Later on im trying to set the value for individual ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $('#myDropdown).dropdown("set text", "some text")
>
> $('#myDropdown).dropdown("set selected", "some text")

For those in future who stumble upon same problem I had.